# Sobre sql e php

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como limitar a quantidade de dados que posso inserir em uma tabela? E quero limitar o campo de vagas para cada rota.

Tabela: alunos.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro`.`alunos` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `matricula` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `comprovanteResidencia` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `rotas_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_alunos_rotas1_idx` (`rotas_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_alunos_rotas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`rotas_id`)
    REFERENCES `cadastro`.`rotas` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Tabela: rotas.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro`.`rotas` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `vagas` INT NULL,
  `partida` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `chegada` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Com esse código utilizando o "TRIGGER" consegui fazer o decremento das vagas:

```
delimiter |
  CREATE TRIGGER men_des BEFORE INSERT ON alunos
  FOR EACH ROW  
      BEGIN  
          UPDATE rotas SET vagas=vagas-1 WHERE id=New.rotas_id;
      END;
| 
delimiter ;
```

Eu li na documentação do MySQL como o amigo aqui me sugeriu, mas acabei me deparando com outro problema, que é o seguinte, Quando as vagas chegam em 0 ainda posso adicionar mais alunos nela e a contagem começa a ficar negativa(-1, -2...).

Comment: Você quer limitar o campo quantidadeVagas de rotas ou limitar a quantidade de registros de alunos que pode incluir para uma dada rota? Para o primeiro caso basta utilizar uma cláusula CHECK e para o segundo uma trigger irá atende-lo

Comment: Limitar a quantidade de registros de alunos para cada rota. Tipo, na tabela rotas o campo quantidadeVagas recebe 4 vagas, com isso só pode se cadastrar 4 alunos naquela rota. Vc pode dar um exemplo de como se usa esse "trigger"?, eu não conheço esse comando. Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Consulte a documentação do MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Faça um tour [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour] e veja como utilizar o StackOverflow. Certamente postar "Não to conseguindo fazer :(" não é a maneira mais adequada de se obter uma resposta.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro o que to querendo fazer. Ficarei aguando. Abrçs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir sua coluna `vagas` como `unsigned` para definir que o inteiro não permite sinal (ou seja, pode ser apenas positivo):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro`.`rotas` (
  --- ...
  `vagas` INT unsigned NULL,
  --- ...
);
```

Além disso você pode adicionar uma restrição com um `CHECK`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro`.`rotas` (
  --- ...
  `vagas` INT unsigned NULL CHECK (vagas > 0),
  --- ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu problema era: Quando cadastrava um novo aluno em uma vaga, na vaga eu não conseguia limitar a quantidade de alunos para a mesma, quando passava da quantidade de vagas disponíveis, no caso menor que 0, a contagem ficava negativa(-1,-2, ...). Ao resolver esse primeiro problema, veio o segundo, que era: Quando atualizava a rota do aluno, nas vagas não atualizava a quantidade de vagas, que no caso era pra decrementar a mesma, mas consegui resolver esses dois problemas com esse código utilizando o TRIGGRER:

```
    delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER dec_vagas BEFORE INSERT ON alunos
    FOR EACH ROW  
        BEGIN
        UPDATE rotas SET vagas=vagas-1 WHERE id=NEW.rotas_id;
        IF (SELECT r.vagas FROM rotas r JOIN alunos a ON r.id=a.rotas_id ORDER BY rotas_id DESC limit 1) < 0 THEN
            SET NEW='Error: Vagas esgotadas!';
            UPDATE rotas SET vagas=0 WHERE id=NEW.rotas_id;
        END IF;
    END;
   | 
   delimiter ;
```

Mas obrigado a todos pela ajuda.